# Does Java guarantee that currently synchronized objects are not garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-memory-model

Is there any guarantee that an object will not be garbage collected while a thread holds its monitor?

e.g.

```java
class x {
    private WeakReference<Object> r;

    Object getMonitorObject() {
        Object o = new Object();
        r = new WeakReference<>(o);
        return o;
    }

    void thread1() throws Exception {
        synchronized (getMonitorObject()) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    void thread2() {
        Object b = r.get();
    }
}
```

In this case concretely, is there any guarantee that `b` will be non-`null` if `thread2()` is called while another thread is sleeping in `thread1()`? Let's just assume the whole of `thread2()` is executed while `thread1()` is sleeping in a different thread.

Comment: While the JLS doesn't pedantically specify that the target of a `synchronized` block must be considered a "strong reference", that implication is clear, and it is in fact. The only problem in this code is that the `WeakReference r` needs to be `volatile` (or use some other memory barrier) to guarantee that the assigned value is visible to the second thread.

Comment: @erickson yes, r should be volatile.

Comment: @erickson I don't think the implication is clear. See JLS 12.6.1 linked by Holger. They consider whether or not synchronization keeps an object alive, and make rules for it under specific circumstances, but not always.

Comment: Yes, ignore the first part of my comment. I was searching JLS 14 and 17, and the `java.lang.ref` package docs, but I didn't think about the consequences of finalization (its use is discouraged nowadays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization can prevent the garbage collection, but not in general. In your specific case, it is not guaranteed.

Compare with [JLS §12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1)

> …
>
> Transformations of this sort may result in invocations of the `finalize` method occurring earlier than might be otherwise expected. In order to allow the user to prevent this, we enforce the notion that synchronization may keep the object alive. If an object's finalizer can result in synchronization on that object, then that object must be alive and considered reachable whenever a lock is held on it.
>
> Note that this does not prevent synchronization elimination: synchronization only keeps an object alive if a finalizer might synchronize on it. Since the finalizer occurs in another thread, in many cases the synchronization could not be removed anyway.

So, since your object has no custom finalizer, no synchronization during finalization may happen and in principle, your object is a temporary object that allows lock elimination, in which case it would not prevent the garbage collection.

But there is the practical obstacle that you stored a `WeakReference` in a way that another thread could retrieve the object while it is not collected and once this possibility exist, the object is not local anymore and lock elimination can not be applied.

A theoretical implementation that aggressively collects the object immediately after construction (or eliminates its existence completely) and clears the weak reference before it escapes or creates an empty `WeakReference` in the first place, would be within the specification, as in that execution scenario, the lock elimination is justified.

---

Note that even if you insert a [`reachabilityFence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence(java.lang.Object)), there is no happens-before relationship between a thread calling `thread1()` and another calling `thread2()`, so the second thread may always behave as-if executing `thread2()` after the other completed the `synchronized` block or passed the reachability fence, even if your real life clock tells otherwise. It’s [said explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) that `Thread.sleep` has no synchronization semantics.

Comment: Later in JLS 12.6.1: "synchronization only keeps an object alive if a finalizer might synchronize on it". That basically tells me that, without a finalizer that might synchronize on the object, the synchronization itself is not *guaranteed* to keep the object alive. Also, yes, `r` should be volatile. `Thread.sleep` was really just to show `thread1()` taking a long time. Testing and logic from the other respondents show that, in practice, synchronization *does* keep the object alive, but I was specifically asking for guarantees, and I think this is the correct answer - there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Jesse that sentence is contained in the cited text. Further note that even if `r` was declared `volatile`, it only guaranteed the caller of `thread2()` to see the weak reference properly, if already written, but it still doesn’t guaranty that thread1 is still inside the `synchronized` block as there still is ordering relationship between leaving the `synchronized` block and anything, `thread2`does.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the end of the `synchronized` block to remove the monitor lock, the `synchronized` block has to keep a reference to the object returned by `getMonitorObject()`.

That reference prevents GC, so answer is yes.

Comment: That sounds practical, but are there any guarantees? It seems plausible that the thread only need retain a reference to the *monitor* itself, not it's owning object. There may be a difference between the object and the monitor.

Comment: @Jesse In Java, the object *is* the monitor.

Comment: JLS 17.1: "Each object in Java is associated with a monitor, which a thread can lock or unlock". Later: "The synchronized statement computes a reference to an object; it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor". Sounds like a possible difference between object and monitor.

Comment: In practice, it is not a difference.  In all implementations of Java that I've encountered, part of the monitor/lock state is in the object's header.

Answer (score 2):

In all Java implementations that I have examined in detail, the state of an object's primitive mutex or lock is represented in part<sup>1</sup> by bits in the object header.  When the lock is released, the JVM needs to update the header bits<sup>2</sup>, so it must still have a reference to the object, either on the stack or in a register.

<sup>1 - When mutex contention occurs, the lock is "inflated" to record extra information.  So we can't say that the *entire* state is in the object header.</sup>

<sup>2 - In most situations, the unlock code won't know if the lock object is unreachable.  But if it did due to aggressive JIT compiler optimization, then hypothetically it could also know that updating the object header was no longer necessary.</sup>

---

But suppose that the object reference wasn't used / needed when unlocking a mutex.

Here is the definition of reachability from the [JLS 12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1):

> "A *reachable* object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."
>   "A *finalizer-reachable* object can be reached from some finalizable object through some chain of references, but not from any live thread."
>
> "An *unreachable* object cannot be reached by either means."

In order for an object to be a candidate for garbage collection, it must not be reachable.  In other words it must not be accessible from any live thread.

What about a mutex that is locked?  Well, the "potential continuing computation" of a thread may need to unlock the mutex:

- If the mutex cannot be unlocked without the reference to the object, then the object is reachable.
- If the mutex can be unlocked without the reference to the object, it can, then the lock *could* be unreachable, or finalizer-reachable.

---

But wait ...

In [JLS 12.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2), there is some complicated language about reachability decision points.

> "At each reachability decision point, some set of objects are marked as unreachable, and  some  subset  of  those  objects  are  marked  as  finalizable."
>
> " If an object X is marked as unreachable at di, then:
>     - ...
>     - All  active  uses  of  X  in  thread  t  that  come-after  di  must  occur  in  the  finalizerinvocation for X or as a result of thread t performing a read that comes-after di of a reference to X; and
>     - ..."
>
> "An action `a` is an active use of `X` if and only if at least one of the following is true:
>     - ...
>     - `a`  locks  or  unlocks  `X`  and  there  is  a  lock  action  on  `X`  that  happens-after  the invocation of the finalizer for `X`.
>     - ..."

Now if I understand it correctly, that is saying that an object which is finalizable cannot be finalized if an active thread *could* still release the corresponding mutex.

---

In summary:

1. In current JVMs, the lock state of a mutex depends on the object header.  If a mutex *could* still be released by a thread, then the object has to be reachable ... as an implementation detail.
2. Assuming that there exists a JVM where a mutex *can* be released without reference to the object, then an object *could* be unreachable while it is still locked.
3. But if the object is finalizable, then it will not be finalized until after all active (application) threads that might need to release the lock have done so.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, I really do appreciate it. I agree that, in practice, the object cannot be destroyed without destroying the monitor. I disagree with your conclusion about JLS 12.6.2: simply unlocking is not an *active use* of `X`. Action `a` is an *active use* if `a` unlocks `X` **and** there is a lock action on `X` that happens-after the invocation of the finalizer for `X`. My scenario does not include the part after "and". I do, however, take your point that, in practice, synchronization does keep the object alive, but I don't think the JLS guarantees is in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across an "aside" in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence(java.lang.Object)) that says this:

> "[The m]ethod `reachabilityFence` is not required in constructions that themselves ensure reachability.  For example, because objects that are locked cannot, in general, be reclaimed, it would suffice if all accesses of the object, in all methods of class Resource (including finalize) were enclosed in synchronized (this) blocks."

This seems to say that objects that are locked cannot be garbage collected.

I'm not sure if that takes precedence over JLS 12.6.1 and 12.6.2; see my other answer, or if we should read this as only applying to Java (language) implementations for the Oracle / OpenJDK Java class libraries.

Comment: I think this talks to the practicalities of it. As you explained, the objects cannot be destroyed without also destroying the mutexes. I don't think this is trying to say "destroying of locked object is forbidden", more like "destroying of locked objects is impractical". Again, thanks for finding this.

Comment: Mind the phrase “all methods of class Resource (**including finalize**) were enclosed in `synchronized (this)` blocks.” It’s a crucial aspect that this class has a nontrivial finalize method and making it `synchronized` establishes a *happens-before* relationship between the last use and the finalization. It also says “Further, such blocks must not include infinite loops, or themselves be unreachable, which fall into the corner case exceptions to the ‘in general’ disclaimer.” which shows that the phrase “in general” can lead to confusion, as it invites to be misinterpreted as “always”.

Answer (score 0):

The sleep method doesn't leave the syncronized block and hence doesn't release the lock or monitor object, it just blocks the execution for a while. Since the lock was never released, garbage collector will not collect it unless the thread that is holding it finishes execution of syncronized block or release it using `wait()` method.

So, yes it is guaranteed to be non null for `thread2()` provided `thread1()` had enough time to finish `getMonitorObject()` call.

**Update**: Aha! Now I see the weak reference there. Silly me!

Yes, weak references are automatically eligible for garbage collection. But it lies within the scope of the class, so it is **not that weak** to say. It will not be eligible for garbage collection unless the instance of class `x` is in scope. So, yes in this case it is *guaranteed to be non null*.

Comment: Do you have a source for this: "Since the lock was never released, garbage collector will not collect it unless the thread that is holding the finish execution"?