# Can GC collect an object which is currently using as a monitor in synchronized block?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, synchronization

Can GC collect an object which is currently using as a monitor in synchronized block?

Suppose I use a reference to an `object1` in a

```
synchronyze(ref){...}
```

some other thread make: `ref = anotherObj`
Is it possible that GC collected the `object1` and the synchronized block failed?

Comment: Well, if we *assume* that "synchronyze" is supposed to read `synchronized`, it *might*

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872699/does-java-guarantee-that-currently-synchronized-objects-are-not-garbage-collecte

Comment: Whether the object gets garbage collected or not, it can not make “the synchronized block failed”. But there is a fundamental problem anyway, when you use `synchronized` with a mutable variable.